# how to create a new form dynamically and inherit the form from an existing form in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there any way in Delphi to inherit from an existing form just before dynamically creating one?
I know how to create a new form dynamically using `tobjects.create()` but I need to create a form that works exactly like an already created form by inheriting that form on creating the new form.

Comment: That's not *inheriting*. It's simply *creating a new instance*, and it's done every time you run your app. `Application.CreateForm` does it in your project flie, and you can do it in your code with `NewForm := TForm1.Create()`, replacing `TForm1` with the name of a form class you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var
       Form2: TForm1;
    begin
       Form2 := TForm1.create(nil);
       try
          // now form2 is exactly "like" form1 when it was created 
          Form2.Top := Form1.Top;
          Form2.Left := Form1.Left;
          // now some of Form2's properties are like Form1's are now                                              
          Form2.ShowModal;
       finally
          Form2.Free;
       end;
```

So the question is, what do you mean by "like"? If there were runtime changes to Form1 since it was created, then you need to apply the same runtime changes to form2 after it is created. Inheritance can't do that for you. Inheritance is the "container", not the data. To copy the "data" of the form, you need to write a procedure that will need to set all the property values of form2 to the property values of form1. Or maybe, just copy the properties you care about.

Comment: thanks for the response sir.I asked this question to know if i can switch to a specified form .

Comment: for example : on some event i need to switch to a form i specified in a editbox

Comment: Ask another question!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
interface
uses Forms, SysUtils, Classes, Controls;

type
    TCommonFormClass = class of TCommonForm;
    TCommonForm = class(TForm)
    private
      // Private declaration
    public
      // Public declaration
      constructor Create(Sender: TComponent); virtual;
    end;

implementation 

constructor TCommonForm.Create(Sender: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(Sender);
  // do other
end;
```

and your child form will be like this

```
type
    TMyForm = class(TCommonForm)
    private
        // Private declaration
    public
        // Public declaration
    end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

to create a child use :

```
procedure CallChild;
var MyForm: TMyForm;
begin
  MyForm:= TMyForm.Create(nil);
  try    
    MyForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    MyForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```